# WordPress: How to make plugin menu visible to user based on capabilities?

Tags: php, wordpress

The current plugin I'm using is only visible to admins as it seems to be written with allowed access to the highest WordPress user level

```
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) exit;

add_action('admin_menu', 'endo_stock_report_admin_menu');

function endo_stock_report_admin_menu() {
    add_menu_page('Stock Report Export', 'Stock Report Export', 10, 'endo_stock_report', 'endo_admin_stock_report_page');
}

function endo_admin_stock_report_page() {

?>
```

I want the plugin to be accessible to users that have the capability to 'upload_files'. I tried the following but am getting a syntax error:

```
if (current_user_can('upload_files')){
    add_action('admin_menu', 'endo_stock_report_admin_menu');

    function endo_stock_report_admin_menu() {
        add_menu_page('Stock Report Export', 'Stock Report Export', 10, 'endo_stock_report', 'endo_admin_stock_report_page');
    }
}
```

I'm not an expert, what am I doing wrong?